# Bizarre issue using OpenCV imshow with matplotlib show

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm trying to simply display an image with OpenCV and plot a figure using MatPlotLib, not necessarily simultaneously. Instead, I am getting an error message in strange cases that I have been unable to decipher. My code is as follows:

```
# These top two import statements were recommended in a related post,
# but do not fix my issue
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Section 1 (showing an image file using cv2):
image = cv2.imread("beach.png")
cv2.imshow("Original", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)


# Section 2 (displaying a simple plt plot):
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

The error I get upon running this code occurs after closing the cv image and is as follows (along with a pop up saying Python has crashed):

```
2017-06-23 11:02:12.408 python[38929:17539609] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100674320
2017-06-23 11:02:12.411 python[38929:17539609] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100674320'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffa9a062cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffbe81148d objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffa9a87f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffa9978755 ___forwarding___ + 1061
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffa99782a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Tk                                  0x0000000104ee0c02 TkpInit + 471
    6   Tk                                  0x0000000104e5c2a9 Tk_Init + 1794
    7   _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x0000000104beedfd Tcl_AppInit + 77
    8   _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x0000000104bec849 _tkinter_create + 889
    9   Python                              0x000000010006a688 _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 568
    10  Python                              0x00000001000f33e4 call_function + 612
    11  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    12  Python                              0x00000001000f27a0 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2720
    13  Python                              0x00000001000f3636 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 422
    14  Python                              0x000000010000e984 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 356
    15  Python                              0x000000010000eaa0 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 208
    16  Python                              0x000000010000e5b3 PyObject_Call + 99
    17  Python                              0x0000000100089871 slot_tp_init + 81
    18  Python                              0x0000000100080144 type_call + 212
    19  Python                              0x000000010000e8d4 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 180
    20  Python                              0x00000001000f3225 call_function + 165
    21  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    22  Python                              0x00000001000f312e fast_function + 606
    23  Python                              0x00000001000f33cb call_function + 587
    24  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    25  Python                              0x00000001000f27a0 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2720
    26  Python                              0x00000001000f28cf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 95
    27  Python                              0x000000010004244a function_call + 186
    28  Python                              0x000000010000e5b3 PyObject_Call + 99
    29  Python                              0x00000001000f7c31 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 17457
    30  Python                              0x00000001000f27a0 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2720
    31  Python                              0x00000001000f2fab fast_function + 219
    32  Python                              0x00000001000f33cb call_function + 587
    33  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    34  Python                              0x00000001000f312e fast_function + 606
    35  Python                              0x00000001000f33cb call_function + 587
    36  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    37  Python                              0x00000001000f27a0 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2720
    38  Python                              0x00000001000f2fab fast_function + 219
    39  Python                              0x00000001000f33cb call_function + 587
    40  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    41  Python                              0x00000001000f27a0 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2720
    42  Python                              0x00000001000f2fab fast_function + 219
    43  Python                              0x00000001000f33cb call_function + 587
    44  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    45  Python                              0x00000001000f27a0 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2720
    46  Python                              0x00000001000f2944 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
    47  Python                              0x000000010012f21e PyRun_FileExFlags + 206
    48  Python                              0x000000010012f4bf PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 447
    49  Python                              0x0000000100148ada Py_Main + 3914
    50  python                              0x0000000100000dfe python + 3582
    51  python                              0x0000000100000c34 python + 3124
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

If I comment out either Section 1 or Section 2 in my code, then the remaining figure is shown properly. Strangely, if I copy Section 2 and paste it again before the first section, the code runs properly and I see all three figures.

I have combed a lot of posts with similar error messages but their common solution to use 'TkAgg' has not solved my issue. I'm using MacOS Sierra and OpenCV 3.2.0. Any other advice would be greatly appreciated, I am very new to OpenCV and fairly new to MatPlotLib!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? Running into the same issue